# VB.NET Console Appilication Equivalent Of Python Input()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console-application

In python to assign an input to a variable with the `input()` function now i know the vb equivalent would be `variable = console.readline` but with python you can specify text in the input eg `name = input("Enter your name")`
Is there such a way to do this in vb without writing them on two seperate lines?

-Thanks

Comment: You would have to create your own method that does that.

Comment: Would writing your own function to do this satisfy your requirement?  Otherwise, `ReadLine` won't write to the console and `WriteLine` won't read from the console.

Comment: Short answer no. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2 it doesn't accept any arguments. As the_lotus said you could simply make your own method which accepts a string and then does a writeline and readline for you. Saves you a bit of typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was said in the comments

```
Public Class LikePython
    Public Shared Function Input(Optional Prompt As String = "") As String
        Console.Write(Prompt)
        Return Console.ReadLine
    End Function
End Class
```

Test

```
Sub Main()
    Dim foo As String
    foo = LikePython.Input
    Stop
    foo = LikePython.Input(">")
    Stop
End Sub
```